# A pop-up element containing a web-view with video

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is it possible to create a pop-up element containing a web-view with uri source (for instance http://www.youtube.com/embed/z-m6Ua9Iqkg)?
How do I make a pop-up window appear after clicking on the button, and in the center of the screen?

1) Yes, I searched internet, but i don't know how to put web view element in pop-up, because after clicking it shows only blank white rectangle (5x10).
2) I used flyout callipso, shows only blank white rectangle (5x10) again :

```
        Flyout flyOut = new Flyout();
        flyOut.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
        flyOut.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;

        WebView web = new WebView();
        web.HorizontalAlignment=HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        web.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        string html = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/z-m6Ua9Iqkg";

        flyOut.Content = web;
        web.NavigateToString(html);
        flyOut.IsOpen = true;

        UpdateLayout();
```

Finally, i have this (Problem solved, thanks to Sachin S from MSDN), i hope this helps someone:

```
Popup popup = new Popup();

        Grid panel = new Grid();

        panel.Height = 250;
        panel.Width = 250;

        panel.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
        panel.Transitions.Add(new PopupThemeTransition());
        WebView web = new WebView();
        //web.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        //web.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        web.Navigate(item.PlayerUri);
        popup.Child = panel;
        panel.Children.Add(web);
        popup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        popup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;


        popup.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2 - panel.Width / 2);
        popup.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2 - panel.Height / 2);

        popup.IsOpen = true;
        UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: You should post the correct code as an answer to this question and accept it as the correct one. that will help others more easily identify the problem and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i have this (Problem solved, thanks to Sachin S from MSDN), i hope this helps someone:

```
Popup popup = new Popup();

        Grid panel = new Grid();

        panel.Height = 250;
        panel.Width = 250;

        panel.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
        panel.Transitions.Add(new PopupThemeTransition());
        WebView web = new WebView();
        //web.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        //web.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        web.Navigate(item.PlayerUri);
        popup.Child = panel;
        panel.Children.Add(web);
        popup.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        popup.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;


        popup.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2 - panel.Width / 2);
        popup.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2 - panel.Height / 2);

        popup.IsOpen = true;
        UpdateLayout();
```